# How to make dynamic background color?

Tags: html, css, rgb

I've got a problem with this script. I don't know how to make dynamic rgb using this. I am javascript noob. I have used three vars and saved using getElementById. And I dont know how to save it to style from the spans.

```
            var i = 0;
    var ii = 20;
    var iii = 18;

function increment() {

   i++;
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = i;
        if (i==255) {
document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = i--;

}
}
    function increment2() { 
   ii++;
    document.getElementById('pica').innerHTML = ii;
        if (ii==255) {
document.getElementById('pica').innerHTML = ii--;
}
}
    function increment3() { 
   iii++;
    document.getElementById('dick').innerHTML = iii;
        if (iii==255) {
document.getElementById('dick').innerHTML = iii--;

}
}   

    setInterval('increment()', 50);
    setInterval('increment2()', 60);
  setInterval('increment3()', 55);
  var rgb = document.getElementById('rgb').innerHTML;   
  document.write(rgb);
```

And this is html:

```
 <div id="rgb">
 <span id="number"></span>
 <span id="pica"></span>
 <span id="dick"></span>
 </div>
```

This is the rgb I need make dynamic:

```
 <div id="id" style="background-color: rgb(255,255,255); 
 width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: Are you able to leverage JQuery?

Comment: I am, but I dont know how

Comment: Like this: http://casewarecomputers.com:8088/soHelp.html?step1=&step2=&step3=&step4=#

Answer (score 4):

[JQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a javascript plugin very used. With it javascript becomes simplier.

In *JQuery* you can access to css properties of an object very simply using [.css() function](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

[Here](http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/) you have a big tutorial about *JQuery*.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info) you have the Stack overflow guide about *JQuery*.

---

***Try this***

```
var r = $('#number').html();
var g = $('#pica').html();
var b = $('#dick').html();

$("#id").css("background-color", "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")");
```

---

***Try this***

**Guidance**:

I think your way to code is inappropiate. By using bad variables name and so one, you do not save time. You confuse yourself.

**1/** Make unique function that modify a rgb value ex

```
  function increment(value)
    {
       value += 1;

       if (value == 256) {
          return 255;
       }

       return value;
    }
```

**2/** Instead of using `span` maybe another solution exist?

---

```js
/**
 * Where we are storing the colors
 */
const colors = {
  red: 0,
  green: 0,
  blue: 0,
};

/**
 * Increment the color by one
 */
function increment(value) {
  value += 1;

  return value == 256 ? 0 : value;
}

/**
 * Gives a random number so we can increase a random color
 */
function getRandomNumber(maxNumber) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(maxNumber));
}

/**
 * Function that's incrementing the colors
 */
function incrementBackground() {
  const randomColorIndexToChange = getRandomNumber(Object.keys(colors).length - 1);

  const keyOfTheColorToChange = Object.keys(colors)[randomColorIndexToChange];

  colors[keyOfTheColorToChange] = increment(colors[keyOfTheColorToChange]);

  $('#myDynamicBackground').css(
    'background-color',
    `rgb(${colors.red}, ${colors.green},${colors.blue})`,
  );

  setTimeout(incrementBackground, 1);
}

setTimeout(incrementBackground, 1);
```

```css
#myDynamicBackground {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDynamicBackground"></div>
```

Comment: I know what's jQuery, but I'll be very pleased if you tell me the code, that I can use

Comment: It looks good, but can you show me how it looks in the code? I am not good in JS. And how can I do the setInterval... For example: http://www.moetbius.cc/ (scroll 1 page down on this site and look on the color changing in logo) — I need this

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage the following code, which (after making only minor changes to yours) calls the updateBgColorDynamically() method.  Which in turn used the .style.backgroundColor and a string concatenation to update the color.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>IrishGeek82 SO Help File</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
                      {
                        increment1();
                        increment2();
                        increment3();
                      }
                    );
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .invalid
    {
        border:1px solid red;
    }

    .noSelect
    {
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    }    
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var iRed   = 0;
    var iGreen = 20;
    var iBlue  = 18;

    function increment1() 
    {

       iRed++;
       document.getElementById('red').innerHTML = iRed;
       if (iRed == 255) 
       {
            document.getElementById('red').innerHTML = 0;
       }
       updateBgcolorDynamically();
    }

    function increment2() {

       iGreen++;
       document.getElementById('green').innerHTML = iGreen;
       if (iGreen==255) 
       {
            document.getElementById('green').innerHTML = 0;
       }
       updateBgcolorDynamically();
    }

    function increment3() 
    { 
       iBlue++;
       document.getElementById('blue').innerHTML = iBlue;
        if (iBlue == 255) 
        {
            document.getElementById('blue').innerHTML = 0;
        }

        updateBgcolorDynamically();
    }       

    function updateBgcolorDynamically()
    {
        document.getElementById("dynamicDiv").style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+iRed+","+iGreen+","+iBlue+")";
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="rgb">
    <span class ="noSelect" id="red" onclick="increment1();">0</span>
    <span class ="noSelect" id="green" onclick="increment2();">0</span>
    <span class ="noSelect" id="blue" onclick="increment3();">0</span>
    <hr>
    <div id="dynamicDiv" style="background-color:rgb(255,255,255);min-width: 100%; min-height: 500px;">
    </div>    
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if that helps :)

Comment: It's doing nothing. Only nulls and white div. Or I am so stupid

Comment: Yeah! I've got it! I have to click!

Comment: I apologize, I thought I'd put that in the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById('id').style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + [a,b,c].join(',') + ')';
```

Comment: That's good, but I don't know how to get the changing number from spans.

Answer (score 0):

**use HSL**  It's all you need.

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/cinuw/1/edit)**

```
var $div = document.getElementById('id'),
    c = 0;   
function changeColor(){
    ++c; // increment counter
    $div.style.backgroundColor = "hsl("+( c%360 )+", 50%, 50%)";
}
setInterval(changeColor, 50);
```

Simply change the **Hue** dynamically, while keeping a desired Saturation to `50%` and Lightness to `50%`.
**Hue** values are from 0 to 360, (0=red, 360=red) and in between you have all your colors palette.
`c%360` (`%`=Reminder operator) is used to reset our `c` counter back to `0`.

```
hsl( HUE[0-360] , SATURATION[0-100%] , LIGHTNESS[0-100%]);
```

<sub>Expore also HSLA colors if you need opacity ;)</sub>